# Purpose of tableView(_:objectValueFor:row:)

Tags: swift, nstableview

[The documentation for the NSTableViewDataSource protocol](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstableviewdatasource/1533674-tableview) says

> This method is mandatory

and if you create a new NSTableViewDataSource the compiler asks you to provide this method as well as `numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView)`.

So far, so good. And if you provide it, it promptly gets called once for every row... but if you delete it, the table seems to work every bit as well as it does without. There seems to be absolutely no connections in a view-based table to this method: in the NSTableViewDelegate's `tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int)` method, I return new views based on the content array of my datasource, and if I stick a bunch of nonsense data into `objectValueFor: row` (up to and including returning the same string - my table objects are not strings) is has no effect whatsoever because I'm setting the values of my NSTableViewCells in `viewFor tableColumn:`.

If I'm handling selection changes (and anything I want to do with objects) by retrieving the corresponding value from the datasource directly (e.g.)

```
func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
print(dataSource.allItems[tableView.selectedRow])
}
```

is there any reason to implement this method? I cannot see any point where that object is actually used, and it feels like an artefact from cell-based tables.

I don't want to break my code by leaving out a necessary method, but since I'm about to try something weird and wonderful with a custom datasource, I also don't want to overcomplicate my code with a method that gets called, but the result of which seems completely meaningless.

Comment: Watch [“View Based NSTableView Basic to Advanced” from WWDC 2011](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/120/). It is very helpful for understanding view-based table views, and discusses the `tableView:objectValueForColumn:row:` method in that context. You can find a transcript of the session [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mayoff/wwdc-session-transcripts/86448e088823690110f1a7e98d2475781ff0c0fd/2011/120.vtt).

Comment: Thanks - I'd watched that some time ago, and the relevant bit slipped past me: "An optional method is tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:. Previously, this was required with the NSCell-based, because it was set to the NSCell value. But now it's optional" which is in direct contrast to the compiler notice and the documentation :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If** the cell view responds to `setObjectValue:`, then the table view calls that method and passes in the object value for the row that was obtained from `tableView(_:objectValueFor:row:)`.

`NSTableCellView` does respond to that method and is a common cell view class. `NSTextField` does, too; it actually inherits it from `NSControl`.

In your case, your cell view either doesn't have an `objectValue` property or, more likely, you're just not using it.

One common configuration is to use `NSTableCellView` as the cell view and then use bindings to bind the subviews to key paths going through its `objectValue` property.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. I've previously set the NSTableCellView's representedObject in viewForTableColumn and used bindings for that; this is a nice way of keeping dataSource and delegate separate. (Despite looking at a lot of examples, I don't think I've ever seen it.) And I hadn't made the connection between objectValue and StringValue, IntegerValue etc...